# How can I obtain the creation date of a DB2 database without connecting to it?

Tags: command, db2, database-connection

How can I obtain the creation date or time of an [IBM's DB2](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/) database without connecting to the specified database first? Solutions like:

```
select min(create_time) from syscat.tables
```

and:

```
db2 list tables for schema SYSIBM
```

require me to connect to the database first, like:

```
db2 connect to dbname user userName using password
```

Is there another way of doing this through a DB2 command instead, so I wouldn't need to connect to the database?

Can `db2look` command be used for that?

---

Edit 01: Background Story

Since more than one person asked why do I need to do this and for what reasons, here is the background story.

I have a server with DB2 DBMS where many people and automated scripts are using it to create some databases for temporary tasks and tests. It's never meant to keep the data for long time. However for one reason or another (ex: developer not cleaning after himself or tests stopping forcefully before they can do the clean up) some databases never get dropped and they start to get accumulated till the hard disk is filled out eventually. So The idea of the app is to look up the age of the database and drop it, if it's older than 6 months (for example).

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what do you need this for? Sounds like an [x-y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: @mustaccio x-y problem? :) good one! I'm automating some procedures to maintain the db  and I want to avoid connecting to many dbs to obtain this info if possible.

Comment: That's what I'd be curious to know: what kind of maintenance depends on when the database was created. What constitutes the creation date, anyway? When you restore a database on a new server, it is created, technically speaking. However, your catalog query will show a different date, possibly from many months or years ago.

Comment: @mustaccio the idea is to delete dbs that are older than X months. Currently I'm doing it through connecting to the db and obtaining its date of creation to determine if I should drop it or not which takes a lot of time to go through 100s of them. If I can obtain this info without connecting to each db, I will save alot of time.

Comment: That's very unusual, I must say. On the topic -- I don't think there is any _reliable_ way to determine that, including the ones that you are using.

Comment: @mustaccio Is there any scenario beside the one which involves moving the databases to another server where such dates won't be reliable? In this scenario the original creation date which is returned is what I need, not the one of migration. So where else do you think this might fail?

Comment: That's precisely why it's unreliable -- neither your nor I nor anyone else can know when it might fail. Since you don't have any control over the catalog tables, you can't be sure if the timestamps you're querying are consistently maintained. Do you know, for example, what happens to them when the database is upgraded?

Comment: I would love to hear why you are doing this.

Comment: @dan1111 Nothing mission critical. It's just a DB2 where people get to create some temporary databases for some quick testing and sometimes they forget to clean after they are done. So my app will go through these databases and drop the old ones to prevent machine running out of storage space.

Comment: Why not just store the creation date for each database?  That way you only have to connect to each DB once, not every time the script is run.

Comment: @dan1111 Oh, I see what you mean. However this is not an issue, because the app is meant to run once every couple of months, not on daily basis. Also because many of these databases are created by other scripts, there is no guarantee that the same database name will be referring to the the same one I checked for couple of months ago because a new db with the same name could have been dropped and re-created many times.